# Obtaining data from child to parent in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I'm making a simple ToDo list and want to pass data from the child `ToDos` component to the parent `Container` component.  The way I am currently doing it works, however I want to be able to access the key attribute which I use in the `Todos` component so that I can simply use its value (index) to splice from the array in the parent.  How can I access the `key` attribute that is defined in `ToDos` in the parent `Container` component?

```
const ToDos = (props) => {
  let todos = props.todos.map((value,index) => {
    return <li key={index} onClick={props.onClick}>{value}</li>
  });
  return <ul>{todos}</ul>
};

class Container extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      input: '', 
      todos: []
    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event){
    this.setState({input: event.target.value})
  }

  handleSubmit(event){
    let arr = this.state.todos;
    let input = this.state.input;
    this.setState({todos: [...arr, input], input: ''})
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  handleClick(event,data){
    let todos = this.state.todos;
    let value = event.target.innerHTML;
    let idx = todos.indexOf(value);
    todos.splice(idx, 1)
    this.setState({todos: todos})
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>My todo List</h1>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <input 
            type='text' 
            value={this.state.input} 
            onChange={this.handleChange} />
          <input type='submit' />
        </form>
        <ToDos onClick={this.handleClick} todos={this.state.todos} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <Container />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Pass something to `props.onClick`

You are already using `props.onClick` to pass data upwards to the parent, why not also pass the `index` there.

```
const ToDos = (props) => {
  let todos = props.todos.map((value,index) => {
    return <li key={index} onClick={event => props.onClick(event, index)}>{value}</li>
  });
  return <ul>{todos}</ul>
};
```

The important part here is **`onClick={event => props.onClick(event, index)}`**

Comment: Thanks, this does what I want. I may be wrong in thinking this, but I thought that the onClick function was being passed from the parent Container component to the child ToDos component and not the other way around.  Also, is this the only way data can be transferred from a child component to a parent component?

Comment: It is being passed from the parent `Container` component as a `prop` to the child `ToDos`. But the child `ToDos` has to call that function, that's what this code is doing but instead of just calling it when an `li` is clicked with `event`, we are passing in `event` and `index`. FYI `onClick={props.onClick}` is the equivalent of `li.addEventListener('click', props.onClick)`

Comment: The most common other way of cross component communication is **State Management**

Answer (score 0):

You can create a **getKey** function in the parent component and assign it to a child prop in the child component.

This way in the child component you may run:

```
this.props.getkey()
```

Hope this helps.